# Where is information from dockerfile located?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

There is a container, that a lot of work was done on (partly within dockerfile, partly within container itself-blatant approach from within) and it got detached from dockerfile. Anyone knows where docker stores information, collected from ENTYPOINT? It's probably some file docker creates, that is been started upon `docker start [container]` `and docker run -it [container sum]`. Need to edit that and really don't want to start from the beginning. Pretty sure don't need to, cause one can work on containers without having original dockerfile.

General documentation on docker site doesn't give any insight into that

I was advised to directly edit `/var/lib/docker/container/[container #]/config.v2.json`
Tried that and the result is the following: If I edit Entrypoint (I'll try to provide image how it looks) - s7.photobucket.com/user/309339939/media/docker.jpg.html

It doesn't help, since the value isn't saved to new after `docker commit`. However, if I change `cmd`, then it is saved. Conclusion: Entrypoint depends on something else besides that file. Any ideas?

Comment: As in, where the data is while running? It's under `/var/lib/docker/containers` or `/var/lib/docker/aufs`, but the folder structure won't help you much. Have a look into `docker commit` to take a snapshot of the new state of the container though.

Comment: Do you have any idea where it stores metadata? It could be there

Comment: It could be there.Trying your way /var/lib/docker/containers seems very promissing. I believe I found a file config.v2.json in my case and there is a history of layers there, with entrypoint and everything. Might be just it - I'll try and update

Comment: slugonamission hi. Tried what you've said. Script doesn't activate upon login - any other ideas? I changed Entrypoint in the file from null to [/etc/./scriptrun]. Image prior to change <a href="s7.photobucket.com/user/309339939/media/docker.jpg.html"; target="_blank"><img src="i7.photobucket.com/albums/y276/309339939/docker.jpg"; border="0" alt=" photo docker.jpg"/></a>

Comment: UPDATE: so this Entrypoint place: if I change it and save, next time I run container, it is null again...Probably depends on something besides that specific place

Answer (score 1):

Docker does not save it's data in the form of a Dockerfile, this file is an input that is "compiled" into the layers and configuration of an image. There are several things you can do to get an idea of the changes, but rebuilding another Dockerfile will be a process that needs to be done by hand:

- `docker history` will give you a list of all the layers and their commands, though many of these commands may not be easily reproducible if outside data was used or you committed a container.
- `docker diff` will show the changes to the filesystem by a container. This is essentially what goes into each layer of a docker image when you build it.
- `docker inspect` will give you all the environment settings and other configurations of an image or container.
- `docker save` will export an image into a tar format that can be later loaded back into another docker engine.

Comment: Those I know...You see, I need a container to start from something, say script of "hello world". Usually I'd put it into dockerfile as entryoint and finita la comedia. In this one I can't do it, so I have to introduce it manually. For that I need to know where it stores this information. Metadata file of some sort probably

Comment: I think a more specific example in your question would help. Provide the exact steps to recreate your problem.

Comment: So here how it was. A dockerfile was compiled, the certain things were installed within container manually. You know docker run -it [container]/bin/bash and you're in. At a certain point a backup was made and...boom...Dockerfile stopped responding. The container should have started a script upon login (ENRYPOINT). And it's 9 h of work...I did what  slugonamission said, found a file and walla-the entrypoint, but updating it doesn't help. Updated to Entrypoint:[./etc/./scriptrun] . Will try to post pic in nex comment

Comment: That's the image of the screen<a href="http://s7.photobucket.com/user/309339939/media/docker.jpg.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i7.photobucket.com/albums/y276/309339939/docker.jpg" border="0" alt=" photo docker.jpg"/></a>

Comment: UPDATE: so this Entrypoint place: if I change it and save, next time I run container, it is null again...Probably depends on something besides that

Comment: Please post these updates as edits to your question. I haven't provided advice to directly edit the files in /var/lib/docker because much of the data there is referenced by checksums so direct changes are unsupported.